# Update previous fragment after back button is pressed inside view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Imagine I have an `Activity` with a `Fragment`, which has a list of contacts and a button to create a new contact.

When I press that button, a second `Fragment` is placed (with `.addToBackStack(null)` and `replace()`) with two fields for contact creation and a button to save it.

I create a new contact and press the back button.

**EDIT**

Being more specific, my project is structured like this:

```
MainActivity
|
|
ContainerFragment
|
|
|_ _ _ Tab A
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 1
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 2
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 3
|        |
|        |_ _ _ ...
|        
|_ _ _ Tab B
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 4
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 5
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 6
|        |
|        |_ _ _ ...
|
|_ _ _ Tab C
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 7
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 8
|        |
|        |_ _ _ Fragment 9
|        |
|        |_ _ _ ...
```

My problem is that `Fragment 2` is able to change things that are shown in `Fragment 1`, after changing it I the back button, `Fragment 2` disappears, But nothing is being called on `Fragment 1`. No `onResume()` or  `onCreateView()`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

From you contacts fragment you can invoke

Contacts Fragment:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);
```

In AddContactFragment

```
...
 Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                //manipulations with you data

                // Package Contact data into an Intent
            Intent data = new Intent();
            ToDoItem.packageIntent(contactName, contactNumber...);
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, data);
                finish();
}
```

And in back in our Contacts Fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST) {
        Contact contact = new Contact(data);
        mAdapter.add(contact);
    }
}
```

Comment: So when I press the back button, no method is called again in my Contacts Fragment?

Comment: if you press back button, you do not need to refresh anything, right?

Comment: I'll be more specific:
I have only one activity in my entire app. The `HomeFragment` contains a list of objects.
When I click on one of them, I load a `AdminFragment`, which actually has a `ViewPager` with 4 different `Fragments`.
One of them is my Contacts fragment, asked in the question.
So what I need to do:
Create a new contact and when I press back, the new contact appears on my list.
But nothing is called, `onResume`, `onCreateView`, nothing!

Comment: Let me clarify as well then do you have a save button in ContactView?

Comment: No, I have to follow the design... But what I think is really weird is that even `onResume` from parent fragment (`ContactsListFrag`) is not being called after back button, don't know if it's because I'm using nested `Fragment`s, or because I have only one activity.

Comment: it is sad to not have button :) when you press back from Contact Fragment do you go back to AdminFragment right?

Comment: AdminFragment contains 4 diferent fragments, because he has a view pager, one of them is my contacts fragment! And inside my contacts fragment I call `.replace()` for the create contact one... A bit confusing and my english is not that good too... sorry

Comment: I did not work with ViewPager. But if in `BasePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter` class you can put a Contact Object and put listeners on all fields of contact. so if the user changes contact info changes will be saved in this object, then your problem will be solved ;)